# Intellij: How to run all main() methods in a folder?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea, main-method

In IntelliJ there is a feature that runs all unit tests in a folder.
Is there any possibility to run all main() methods in the same way?

Answer (score 3):

Not that I am aware of.

Workaround with wrapper class:

Create a class with a `main` method and call every `main` method in that method.

If these classes with `main` methods changes a lot, you could use this [Reflection Library](https://github.com/ronmamo/reflections) with the following code to scan for classes with a `main` method:

```
 Reflections reflections = new Reflections("your.package.with.main.classes");

 Set<Class<? extends Object>> allClasses = 
     reflections.getSubTypesOf(Object.class);
```

The `allClasses` set contains all classes in that package.

The following code would filter for classes that have a `main` method:

```
Set<Class> mainClasses = allClasses.stream()
  .filter(clazz -> 
    Arrays.stream(clazz.getMethods())
     .anyMatch(method -> 
        method.getName().equals("main")))
   .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Calling the `main` method should not be problem anymore.

PS: A filtering for `static` and `public` modifier would be a good idea as well.